# How to achieve 2 way data binding on a div's innerhtml property using ngModel?

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, data-binding

In my angular component ts file I have a model, with a property whose value is html formatted text. 
The text is displayed in the UI using inner html property of a div in my component’s .html file.
The div is made editable by setting the editable property .

Code snippet :

```
<div id="requestBody" contenteditable="true" 
*ngIf="selectedReqTab==='reqBody'" [innerHTML]="formatJson(requestBody)"></div>
```

Here formatJson returns the html formatted JSON text.

The issue :

The changes made in the text are not getting reflected in the corresponding model, even if we have 2 way data binding using ngModel.

```
<div id="requestBody" contenteditable="true" 
*ngIf="selectedReqTab==='reqBody'" [(ngModel)]=”requestBody” 
[innerHTML]="formatJson(requestBody)"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong here ? could you please suggest.

Comment: As far as I am aware, a `contenteditable` element doesn't fire a `change` event, which is what `ngModel` two-way binding relies on. Try binding to the `input` or `keyup` events. If you do that, I'd advise creating an Observable from them so that you can use operators like `debounceTime` and `distinctUntilChanged` to avoid getting too many events.

Answer (score 2):

`contenteditable` isn't an input, and two way binding works on inputs.

You have to update your model through `input` events, [as shown here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kyqild)

```
<p (input)="updateModel(model.innerText)" #model contenteditable>{{ name }}</p>
```

Comment: The issue with this solution, as we can see in the stackblitz, is after edition the cursor go back at the beginning. It happens because the view is updated with the new value coming from {{ name }}.