# How to achieve 2 way data binding on a div's innerhtml property using ngModel

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I have a textarea and whatever HTML is typed inside that textarea will be previewed in a div and that div is editable.so if I modify anything in the div that should reflect the same in HTML inside the textarea. suppose there is a `<h1> hello world </h1>` in textarea and it will be previewed as `hello world` in div and i erased the `world` and then HTML in textarea should become `<h1>hello</h1>`. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320588/how-to-achieve-2-way-data-binding-on-a-divs-innerhtml-property-using-ngmodel) and tried adding ngModel to the div but both didn't work. [this the stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngmodel-ngmodel-for-html-output-5kzpnb). thankyou.

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  content = 
`<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>This is a great example...</p>
`;
}
```

```html
<textarea 
  [(ngModel)]="content"
  cols="50" 
  rows="10">
  </textarea>

<br><br><br>

<div [innerHtml]="content" contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo. It looks like you're trying to use contentNew rather than content so this should fix your current binding issue.
(input)="content=$event.target.textContent"

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

**component.html**

```
<textarea 
  [(ngModel)]="content"
  cols="50" 
  rows="10"></textarea>

<br><br><br>

<div [innerHtml]="content" contenteditable="true" (input)="updateModel($event)" #model>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
content = `<h2>Hello</h2>
             <p>This is a great example...</p>
            `;
  updateModel(event) {
     console.log(event.target.innerHTML)
     setTimeout(()=> {
     this.content = event.target.innerHTML;
     }, 1000)
   }
```

Comment: Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngmodel-ngmodel-for-html-output-ax3ry3

Comment: I didn't understand why `setTimeout` and the previewed div is focusing out

Comment: previewed div is focusing out because of to textarea and previewed div both in synch

Comment: how can I fix that